# showing that there exist x,y with $xc+yd=1$ mod n

Tags: number-theory

$a$ and $b$ are zero divisors in $\mathbb{Z}/(n)$ (one of $a$ or $b$ could be also $0$) and $n$ is a prime power.

$a=gcd(a,b,n)\cdot c$ and $b=gcd(a,b,n)\cdot d$.

(*) I want to show that there exist $x,y\in \mathbb{Z}$ with $xc+yd\equiv 1\mod n.$

$k=gcd(a,b,n)$. It is clear that $\exists \ x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $k=xa+yb+zn$ and that $x\cdot k\cdot c+y\cdot k \cdot d+z\cdot n-gdc(a,b,n)=1$. But how can I show (*)?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two key facts that you should be able to prove without trouble.

Let $n = p^k$, where $p$ is prime.

- Every divisor of $n$ is a power of $p$.
- Every nonzero integer $x$ can be written uniquely in the form $x = p^m y$, where $\gcd(y,p) = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=p^m$, $p$ prime, $m>1$ (If $m=1$, we can't have zero divisors) 
. $a$ and $b$ are zero divisors, then $a=p^\alpha, b=p^\beta$ with $\alpha,\beta<m$.
Of this way,  $\text{gcd}(a,b,n)=\text{gcd}(a,b)=k$.
We can write then $a=kc, b=kd$. Is easy to verify that $\text{gcd}\left(\dfrac{a}{k},\dfrac{b}{k}\right)=1=\text{gcd}(c,d)$. By Bezout, there exists $x, y$ s.t. $xc+yd=1\equiv 1 \mod{n}$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But in $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}$ $6=3\cdot 2$ is a zero divisor. And I forget to say that a $a$ or $b$ could be zero, so $gdc(a,b,n)$ is not alway the same like $gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: You're right. But if a,b\neq 0, then write a=a'*p^\alpha, b=b'*p\alpha. We can suppose WLOG \beta\geq\alpha, then gcd(a,b,n)=p^\alpha=gcd(a,b) and we have the same than before.  If one of them is zero, it can be written in the form \rho*p\eta, with \eta\geq m. Then you can conclude the same, or not?

Comment: Because of this way, one of them has to be n

Comment: Yes you are right the first one is the same proof, but if one of them ist zero, than for example gcd(6,0)=6 but gcd(6,0,8)=2, so $p^a(x,0)$ with x is a unit, but than you can conclude gcd(x,n)=1, so it is ok. Maybe you mean the same and I didn't understand :). Thank you I think now it is clear.